# How to unregister events in electron?

Tags: electron

I am making an application using atom-shell that needs to load several html pages. Each time I load a different page, I need to execute some custom script. For this I am using `mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', ...)`. But since I need to have a custom function for each file, I would like to unregister from the did-finish-load event.

Example:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load',function() {
    console.log('loaded page1');
    mainWindow.webContents.unregister('did-finish-load') // <= does that exist?
});
mainWindow.loadUrl('file://.../page1.html');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`BrowserWindow` extends `EventEmitter`, so you would remove a listener the same way you typically would in Node.js:

```
var handler = function () {
    // ...
};
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', handler);

// Later:
mainWindow.webContents.removeListener('did-finish-load', handler);
```

Comment: Hi, i m new to electron, if it is the same EventEmitter as nodejs, once method can handle that easily. https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener, is it ?

Comment: That's a good point, and yes, that should work too.  I suppose I answered the question perhaps a little too directly as it related to unregistering a listener.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro I am having the same problem, but it is the other way around. I have used the mainWindow.webContents.send from main file and registered it in the renderer using Ipcrenderer.on in created lifecycle hook. Now how can i remove that listener in a correct way. Here's my [Ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906065/electron-js-event-is-firing-multiple-times/63906232?noredirect=1#comment113047952_63906232)